# Strategy to understand code I can't get

Tags: c++, debugging, fibonacci

**Quick method to quickly compute Fibonacci, using Matrix property**

```
Divide_Conquer_Fib(n) {
    i = h = 1;
   j = k = 0;
   while (n > 0) {
     if (n%2 == 1) { // if n is odd
     t = j*h;
     j = i*h + j*k + t;
     i = i*k + t;
  }
t = h*h;
h = 2*k*h + t;
k = k*k + t;
n = (int) n/2;
} 
   return j;
```

}

How do i understand this code? What would your strategy be? Would you put lots of print statements to see how states of variables change? 
It is important to see how various developers' minds would go about understanding this code.

Comment: I would see how it behaves for 1,2,3,2n,2n+1 as this algorithm works on even and odd. And I would use paper and pen instead of printf

Comment: i would grab a piece of paper and "run the function" using my pencil for a very simple case

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for programmer's opinions, and stating that it's "important to see how various developers' minds would go about understanding this code," which is vastly off-topic for this site.


Comment: It is still interesting :)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, i want to see developer process in mind - what he thinks

Comment: @ERJAN Actually, I should have said - this is a much better suited question for [programmers.se].  That's the site for discussing the process of programming.  This site is for specific issues.  You don't seem to have any issue with this algorithm, you just want a discussion about how others (and not **you**) evaluate it.

Comment: run it in a debugger too. Every dev needs to know how to do this, learning to do it with simple programs will set you up for debugging bigger ones

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by running it against a few vales of n to check that it actually appears to give the correct answers.  Then I'd read up on the mathematical theory to understand how it is likely to be working, and finally use that knowledge to take it to bits…

The Wikipedia entry section on the [Matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) explains the basis for this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the proper way to look at this code is to know what it does: Fibonacci numbers are coming up as an interesting exercise frequently, plus there is quite a bit of context saying what it does: it uses a matrix property together with divide and conquer. It turns out that you can compute the vector *(Fib<sub>n</sub>, Fib<sub>n-1</sub>)* as a product of some matrix and *(Fib<sub>n-1</sub>, Fib<sub>n-2</sub>)*. Let's assume two rows in the code below are just two rows of the same matrix:

```
(Fib[n]  )    (1  1)   (Fib[n-1])
(        )  = (    ) * (        )
(Fib[n-1])    (1  0)   (Fib[n-2])
```

Now, matrix multiplication of quadratic matrices is associative, i.e., if the matrix above is *M* you can compute *Fib<sub>n</sub>* as *M<sup>n</sup>* times *(1, 0)*.

The next step is to compute *M<sup>n</sup>* using divide and conquer. The basic trick here is that *M<sup>n</sup>* can be decomposed according to the bits of *n*: Instead of computing the power by *n* multiplication you decompose the computation into computing squares and multiplying an extra term if the value is odd.

This is the basic underlying approach. The computation of the powers is done in the other direction, however, which works - I *think* - because the matrix is symmetric. I don't think you can derive the algorithm from the code easily if you are unaware of the basic approach.